# Eclipse / launch / Java Classpath enclosed in quotes / breaks 3rd party tools / blocks development

Tags: gwt, eclipse-jdt, spring-tools-4, gwt-2.8

see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558712

In Eclipse 4.14, java.class.path Java property is enclosed in quotes for launch configurations

More specifically for GWT Development Mode launch configurations.

We are suspecting that the classpath is long enough and it is thus enclosed in quotes for safety.

However, this breaks the GWT run itself as the gwt-dev code looks for the classpath and splits it expecting the classpath not to be enclosed in quotes.
see getClassPath() method of https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/2.8.2/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/cfg/ResourceLoaders.java

This started happening after updating Eclipse IDE.

We are using Spring Tool Suite 4 version 4.5.0 which I believe is built on Eclipse 4.14.
We are confident that the parts that produce the classpath are Eclipse IDE specific and not Spring Tools 4 specific.
Therefore we consider the problem clearly Eclipse related.

This is currently blocking our development work and is jeopardizing delivery of our commercial projects because our developers cannot run our applications on their development machines.

We believe this is Eclipse JDT related
something must have changed in most recent Eclipse JDT releases
as this used to be working roughly a month ago or less

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this got fixed in Eclipse 4.15M1 (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558712#c3). We will setup early access CI builds for Spring Tools 4 on Eclipse 4.15 milestone builds asap, so that you can get that fix as soon as possible from: http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html

Comment: Thank for the quick response.
We will wait for the nightly build.
Let us know when the fix becomes available.

Comment: I think the latest CI build of Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse 4.15 from http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html should contain the fix in Eclipse, if you would like to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I confirm that the problem is resolved in Version: 4.5.1.CI-B2125 Build Id: 202001062305

Comment: Awesome, great to hear. Thanks for trying the latest CI.